# Why is the table cutoff in Chrome but not Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, next.js

I'm currently following a tutorial in order to learn how to create a dashboard to track cryptocurrency prices. However, I have become stuck on an issue where the top of my tables gets cut off when I run the webpage on chrome [image], while the top of the webpage is supposed to look like this at the top of the webpage as can be seen when ran on IE [image]. When I disable javascript within Chrome I get something like [image]. The program's backend uses next.js, coingecko API to fetch prices and bootstrap for formatting. I would greatly appreciate any tips that could help in pushing me towards the solution. I have attached the relevant code and resources below.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import CoinGecko from 'coingecko-api';
const coinGeckoClient = new CoinGecko();

export default function Home(props) {
  const { data } = props.result;

  const formatPercent = number => 
    `${new Number(number).toFixed(2)}%`

  const formatDollar = (number, maximumSignificantDigits) =>
    new Intl.NumberFormat(
      'en-US', 
      { 
        style: 'currency', 
        currency: 'USD',
        maximumSignificantDigits
      })
      .format(number);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Coinmarketcap clone</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <h1>Coinmarketcap clone</h1>

      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>24H Change</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Market cap</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(coin => (
            <tr key={coin.id}>
              <td>
                <img 
                  src={coin.image} 
                  style={{width: 25, height: 25, marginRight: 10}} 
                />
                {coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}
              </td>
              <td> 
                <span
                  className={coin.price_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? (
                    'text-success' 
                  ) : 'text-danger'}
                >
                {formatPercent(coin.price_change_percentage_24h)}
                </span>
              </td>
              <td>{formatDollar(coin.current_price, 20)}</td>
              <td>{formatDollar(coin.market_cap, 12)}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  )
}
```

- Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klFeYge2G0I
- Repo: https://github.com/jklepatch/eattheblocks/tree/master/screencast/226-coinmarketcap-clone

Comment: Why do you need to support IE? This is a dead browser. Ignore how it looks there. Especially for tutorials.

Comment: My intentions are not to specifically support IE. I want to run it correctly on Chrome, which is giving the cut-off issues. IE was only used as a test/example.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but, I find `justify-content: center` in `.container` CSS class. Try removing that. We don't what bootstrap adds too it, try commenting it's import in `_app.js`.

Comment: @VijayDev I removed `justify-content: center` from the `.container` within the `Home.module.css` file and everything seems to be working correctly. Thank you very much!